# Spring, Hibernate, TestNG and h2: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testng, h2

I'm trying to test the DAO layer.
The project comprises the following stack of technologies: Spring 4, Hibernate 5, MySQL, H2, Mockito, testNG, dbUnit and other...

Here a fragment of dependences from pom.xml:

```xml
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa.version>
    <mysql-connector.version>5.1.38</mysql-connector.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
    <h2.version>1.3.176</h2.version>
    <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The result of the test returns the following error stack:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: user

    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:192)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:98)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:67)
    SEE ====> at ru.ts.js.oxaoo.srt.dao.DAOTest.setUp(DAOTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

The description of a configuration of testing for a Hibernate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"ru.ts.js.oxaoo.srtd.dao"})
public class HibernateTestConfiguration {

    //@Autowired
    //private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"ru.ts.js.oxaoo.srtd.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:srtd;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

The abstract class for testing of all DAO:

```
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HibernateTestConfiguration.class})
public abstract class DAOTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        IDatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseDataSourceConnection(dataSource);

        IDataSet dataSet = getDataSet();
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, dataSet);
    }

    protected abstract IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception;
}
```

The same code line #30 on the spot where the error occurs:

```
DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbConn, dataSet);
```

Contents of variables during debugging before execution of this code line:
[img contents of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ba3a.png). Almost all fields in dbConn is null.

Class the testing user DAO:

```
public class UserDAOTest extends DAOTest {
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserDAOTest.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    protected IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
        return new FlatXmlDataSet(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("user.xml"));
    }

    @Test
    public void findById(){
        if (userDAO == null) log.info("user dao is null");
        else log.info("user dao is: " + userDAO.toString());
        UserEntity ue = userDAO.findByPK("ivan@email.com");
        log.debug("Find by id: " + ue.toString());
        assertNotNull("Don't found user by id", ue);
    }
}
```

And these contents of the user.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <user email="ivan@email.com"    idPassanger="1"     password="qwerty"/>
    <user email="petr@email.com"    idPassanger="2"     password="qwerty2"/>
    <user email="dmitry@email.com"  idPassanger="3"     password="12345"/>
</dataset>
```

The error refers to the "user" tag from this file as I understood.

Also here user's POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "srtd")
public class UserEntity {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private PassangerEntity idPassanger;

    public UserEntity() {}

    public UserEntity(String email, String password, PassangerEntity idPassanger) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.idPassanger = idPassanger;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPassanger", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public PassangerEntity getIdPassanger(){
        return idPassanger;
    }

    public void setIdPassanger(PassangerEntity idPassanger){
        this.idPassanger = idPassanger;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;

        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", idPassanger=" + idPassanger.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In completer stack of errors the following a log on which it seems to me meets it is necessary to pay attention:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:
Schema "SRTD" not found; SQL statement:
alter table srtd.user add constraint FKec3wluojmxshecxg06rihvlwf foreign key (idPassanger) references srtd.passanger [90079-176]
```

If it is necessary, then I will lay out a complete stack of errors, the truth it there is very big...

Please help me to solve this problem, I have already spent the whole day on it.

Comment: I guess the issue could be because sensitive schema name. Can you try with updated url `jdbc:h2:mem:srtd;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;IGNORECASE=TRUE`. Not sure if we need `schema = "srtd"` in `entity` annotation as the above url already has it.

Comment: Yes! You were right. I removed the annotation scheme entity and it worked. I'm really grateful to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the attribute `schema = "srtd"` from the `entity` annotation as the `dataSource.setUrl(..)` method already has it.